# RDP to HTTP Converting

Tags: c#, tcp, rdp

Last few months I was in a research project to make a windows application to share screen, with more advance features such as "Share selected application only". Even though I got all the features NAT hall punching made a bottleneck for the communication. Still I'm unable to overcome that problem. So I decided to use a relay for the communication. following image shows the idea in my mind.

[image]

Here I need to to access the RDP data to convert them to byte arrays. Then I can send them over the HTTP.

According to the result of my research RDP is the best technology that is suitable for the screen sharing (Windows)application. That's why I'm trying to continue with RDP.

Any one who has any of the idea about this conversion, Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the entire RDP concept from your mind, it is not relevent to the problem at hand. All you need to do is connect one TCP application to a 2nd TCP application via a 3rd party proxy. This is a classic [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or [Tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) situation, go look for examples of how to design a VPN/tunnel system or pick up a pre-built library for one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to find a method that can use RDP. that is my task. I agree with you about the VNC which is using frame buffer exchanging technique. but as I got RDP is more efficient than that, because it is sending meta data instead whole frame buffer. It is more efficient than VNC. That is why i'm trying to use RDP

Comment: Not VNC, VPN (Virtual Private Network). And really you are more using tunneling than doing a full VPN. Look for tunneling solutions like SSH or others. Heck, here is a project that [tunnels TCP over HTTP](https://code.google.com/p/supertunnel/)